# How to merge the SQL table Rows if previous row EndTime and current row StartTime is equal entry?

Tags: sql-server

I want to merge the table row values into a single row if previous row End-Time and current row Start_Time values is matched.

**For example:**

| S.No | Start_Date | End_Date | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-12-20 10:25:49.000 | 2021-12-20 10:30:56.000 | 100 |
| 2 | 2021-12-20 10:10:00.000 | 2021-12-20 10:20:00.000 | 10 |
| 3 | 2021-12-20 10:00:00.000 | 2021-12-20 10:10:00.000 | 10 |
| 4 | 2021-12-20 09:55:00.000 | 2021-12-20 10:00:00.000 | 5 |

Here s.no 4, 3 & 1 End_Date & Start Date is matching. In this case I want to merge this row's a single row.

**I am expecting below results:**

| S.No | Start_Date | End_Date | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-12-20 10:25:49.000 | 2021-12-20 10:30:56.000 | 100 |
| 2 | 2021-12-20 09:55:00.000 | 2021-12-20 10:20:00.000 | 25 |

```
**New Column (FCode) Added.**

S.No      Start_Date             End_Date        Duration  FCode
1     2021-12-20 10:25:49   2021-12-20 10:30:56    100     Null
2     2021-12-20 10:10:00   2021-12-20 10:20:00    10      101
3     2021-12-20 10:00:00   2021-12-20 10:10:00    10      110
4     2021-12-20 09:55:00   2021-12-20 10:00:00    5       109



**I am expecting this below result: Based on Start_Date**

S.No      Start_Date               End_Date             Duration  FCode
1720    2021-12-20 09:55:00   22021-12-20 10:20:00.000    25    109
```

Comment: You have added the duration column of 4,3 and 2. But say 4, 3, &1 have matching start and end dates. You also have no matching start or end dates in that list as the column is Date Time. If you just had the date they would all match. So what you have doesnt make much sense

Comment: Your data is wrong likewise output if you are trying to merge those 2,3,4 reason being it lies within min and max datetime ranges then why not just have 1 record of min(start_range) and max(end_range)

Comment: I want to compare previous row endtime and current row start time. IF matches, then I need to filter it out and make the changes.   For Example: Sno 4 EndTime is 2021-12-20 10:00:00.000 Also in Sno 3 StartTime is equalent to the previous date.

Comment: So if the end date is equal to the start date of another row, you want them to be merged?

Comment: Yes, Exactly. Hope you can  understand my requirement.

Answer (score 2):

**This is a classic *gaps-and-islands* problem.**

There are many solutions, here is one:

- Identify the beginning of each island using `LAG`
- Assign a group number to each island using a windowed `COUNT`
- Group by that ID and aggregate

```sql
WITH Prev AS (
    SELECT *,
      IsStart = CASE WHEN LAG(End_Date) OVER (ORDER BY Start_Date) = Start_Date THEN NULL ELSE 1 END
    FROM YourTable t
),
Groupings AS (
    SELECT *,
      GroupId = COUNT(p.IsStart) OVER (ORDER BY p.Start_Date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM Prev p
)
SELECT
  [SNo] = MIN(t.[SNo]),
  Start_Date = MIN(t.Start_Date),
  End_Date = MAX(t.End_Date),
  Duration  = SUM(t.Duration)
FROM Groupings t
GROUP BY t.GroupId;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a9a990e595052cc2f47c3a03d3cbb3da)

Comment: Great its works fine, thanks a lot for your valuable support.

Comment: I want to take new column values after that duration, I have FaultId.  Which values like 100,120,0,0,0. In this Case, I don't want to get sum of min/max values. I need get the based on Min start_date result row values.   For Example:    
   SNo               Start_Date                                     End_Date                 Duraion                                                        
  1720 2021-11-30 02:26:51.000 2021-11-30 02:31:31.000 4.68                                      Based on Start_Date i want to get result. But i am getting  "Error :  'Groupings.TEFault_Id'  aggregate."

Comment: You are no being very clear. This new column wasn't in your question, and I don't quite understand what kind of aggregation you want

Comment: I have updated the questions. Please check my new table column added FCode in the questions.

Comment: Add `MIN(FCode)` to the final `SELECT`

Comment: That is faultcode sometime I will get some random values also. In this case getting min value will not work right. I want to get based on Faut code Start_Date time. Hope you understand it. Please let me know if you need any example.

Comment: Updated the new table. In this case if i am adding Min(FCode) the result should be 101. But i want result of the fault code is when Downtime started. My downtime started at 2021-12-20 09:55:00. So, I want relevant Fcode. i.e: 109.

Comment: Then `MIN(CASE WHEN IsStart = 1 THEN FCode END)` should do the trick

Comment: Perfect & Great. Thanks it's working perfectly.

Comment: After Merge the rows. I want to delete the unwanted rows in the table. Can you please help here to solve it.  For Example: Once merge done i want to delete the row of  Sno 2&3

Comment: I suggest you create a *new* question if you want help with that. You could just dump it all into a temporary table, truncate the old one and re-insert